# get info for GBDT model tree information

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using [GBDT](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) from sklearn learn, I am wondering is there is any way to get the final trained GBDT tree information? My understanding is, if I setup max 500 tree and max 10 depth for each tree, it is the an upper limit, I want to get an actual number of tree used, and actual depth of each tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation page you linked to lists the following attribute:

```
estimators_ : ndarray of DecisionTreeRegressor,shape (n_estimators, loss_.K)

    The collection of fitted sub-estimators. loss_.K is 1 for binary classification, otherwise n_classes.
```

So, you should be able to get individual trees in the order they get added to the model.

Additional comments: the actual number of trees used in the model will be equal to a parameter `n_estimators`, unless early stopping is used, then it could be less and it's stored in the following attribute:

```
n_estimators_ : int

    The number of estimators as selected by early stopping (if n_iter_no_change is specified). Otherwise it is set to n_estimators
```

The depth is maximized, unless there is not enough samples per leaf/split and other parameter limitation.

Comment: Thanks, which part of this page (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) do you find the above info?

Comment: in `Attributes` section